# Generating JWT Token with RSA256 + Passcode

Tags: java, jwt, rsa

I am attempting to sign a JWT token using a RSA256 private key that has a passphrase.

Here's the code that I am using the generate the passphrase:

```
byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(key);
Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());
JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().setIssuedAt(now).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, signingKey);
LOGGER.info(builder.compact());
```

I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RSA signatures must be computed using an RSA PrivateKey.  The specified key of type javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec is not an RSA PrivateKey.

The error implies that there is something invalid with the private key, however I did validate it using JavaScript and it seems to work fine (Which allows me to provide a passPhrase). However with Java I'm having trouble finding the documentation on providing a passPhrase.

Comment: What format does the private key have? Encrypted PKCS8?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use SecretKeySpec here. A private key is not a secret key.

Comment: Hey @derpyderp where you able to sort it out? I am having the exact same situation in Scala. I am able to sign the token using JavaScript however it becomes pain when trying to do it in scala any help is highly appreciated.